# Transaction timeout for a JmsListener?

Tags: transactions, timeout, spring-jms

I thought I could mark a JMSListener as @Transactional and then specify the timeout like this...

```
@Component
public class MyListenerClass {

  @JmsListener(destination = "someQueue")
  @Transactional(timeout = 600)  // 10 minute timeout
  public void receiveMessage(Foo foo) {
    Thread.sleep(360,000); // Sleep for 6 minutes to test timeout
  }
}
```

Our JBoss server is configured with a 5 minute timeout.  Even though I specified a 10 minute timeout in the annotation, I see the transaction reaper roll back the transaction at the 5 minute mark.   I turned on trace logging for org.springframework.transaction, I can see when the receiveMessage() method is called is participates in an existing transaction instead of creating a new transaction.  That's why I'm getting the 5 minute timeout instead of the 10 minute timeout.

After thinking about it, that makes sense.  Under the covers, I'm guessing it's the JmsListenerContainer that starts the transaction, reads the message and then calls my receiveMessage() method.  Is that basically correct?

If I am correct, how can I control the transaction timeout?   I'm assuming it's done somehow when we configure the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory shown below.  But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {

    // Setup a new Factory and configure it using the auto-configuration Spring came up with.
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

    // Now we can make some additional changes to it. 
...

    return factory;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug through the Spring code and came up with a solution.  I'm not sure it's the best solution but it works.

The transaction timeout can be set on the DefaultMessageListenerContainer.  The problem is that with @JmsListener, the DefaultMessageListenerContainer is created by the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.  Unfortunately there is no way to tell the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory to configure the transaction timeout on the DefaultMessageListenerContainer it creates.

So I had to create a sub-class of DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory that allows us to set the transaction timeout and then configure it on every DefaultMessageListenerContainer it creates, like this...

```
public class TransactionTimeoutAwareDefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory extends DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory {

    @Nullable
    private Integer transactionTimeout;

    public void setTransactionTimeout(Integer transactionTimeout) {
        this.transactionTimeout = transactionTimeout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeContainer(DefaultMessageListenerContainer container) {
        super.initializeContainer(container);

        if(transactionTimeout != null) {
            container.setTransactionTimeout(transactionTimeout);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can configure the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory using that new class...

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {

    // Setup a new Factory and configure it using the auto-configuration Spring came up with.
    // this step is important to be sure we use the JBoss JMS ConnectionFactory.
    TransactionTimeoutAwareDefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new TransactionTimeoutAwareDefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

    // Set the transaction timeout to 10 minutes
    factory.setTransactionTimeout(600);

    // Configure the rest of the options for the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory
    ...

    return factory;
}
```